# AppHarbor doesn't deploy app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, visual-studio-2012, appharbor

I have a VS 2012 solution with ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

When I puch my code into repository the build starts, but application doesn't get deployed.

I've tried to deploy by clicking 'Deploy' button but it doesn't help either.

Build log:

"Branch name

master

Commit ID

183189fa65829e9d94797744e249bcd5b4c57858

Commit message

test

Log

Time    Message 
6/26/13 7:47 PM Received notification, queuing build
6/26/13 7:47 PM Downloading source
6/26/13 7:47 PM Downloaded source in 8.88 seconds
6/26/13 7:47 PM Starting build
6/26/13 7:47 PM 0 warnings
6/26/13 7:47 PM Build completed in 4.28 seconds Show Log
6/26/13 7:47 PM Starting website precompilation 
6/26/13 7:48 PM Precompilation completed in 22.64 seconds
6/26/13 7:48 PM Starting tests
6/26/13 7:48 PM Tests completed in 6.54 seconds 
Tests

Build contains no tests"

Comment: What does the log show?

Comment: After 8 hours (!) it has been deployed. I wasn't aware that you need to wait so long...

Comment: That's definitely abnormal, consider contacting support.